# ASPNET Core SignalR Cors Policy

Tags: .net, cors, signalr

I am consistently getting CORS issues when I attempt to hit my ASP.NET Core API SignalR endpoint. I believe I have it configured to allows all Headers, Method, when the origin is my localhost.

[image]

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Services

// Hubs
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<ChessHub>("/hubs/chess");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2):

app.UseCors(), Should be between app.UseRouting() and app.UseAuthentication();
Also, you have not added AddCors Service.

```
builder.Services.AddCors()
```

Try the below Code.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Services

// Hubs
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<ChessHub>("/hubs/chess");

app.Run();
```

Comment: I have spent my time resolving the issues of others, and they downvoted it, without explaining the reason. And they think this is appreciating me. Ok, Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I will help you.